# Where are importScripts files loaded from?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

The [MDN definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) is pretty short:

> The `importScripts()` method of the `WorkerGlobalScope` interface imports one or more scripts into the worker's scope.

When using `importScripts("foo.js")`, where is `foo.js` loaded from? I would like to know what happens in the following cases:

- `foo.js` is not cached and not loaded on page by someone else. Is `foo.js` loaded from disk?
- `foo.js` is cached. Probably it's loaded from cache, right?
- `foo.js` is loaded on page already (using `<script src="foo.js"></script>`). Is `foo.js` loaded from memory? If not, where is it loaded from?

Comment: … I must admit that I'm not entirely sure how much detail you're looking for. Are you asking "how do browsers determine if they need to load a script file"? I'm pretty sure `importScripts` just uses the same mechanisms that `<script src></script>` does.